# How to join 1 column of table 1 with table 2, and another one with table 2 again

Tags: abap

I have two tables,  like below:
`Table1`

| VBELN | STAT1 | STAT2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |
| 2 | B | C |

`Table2`

| STATS | DESC |
| --- | --- |
| A | This is A |
| B | This is B |
| C | This is C |

I am trying to derive the description for each Stat and populate as a single row:
`Expected results`:

| VBELN | STAT1 | STAT1DESC | STAT2 | STAT2DESC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | This is A | B | This is B |
| 2 | B | This is B | C | This is C |

I tried combining both using `INNER JOIN` but I am not sure how to fulfill it at one-go:

| VBELN | STAT1 | STAT1DESC | STAT2 | STAT2DESC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | This is A | B |  |
| 2 | B | This is B | C |  |

How do I achieve the expected result using JOINS?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? If so can you share your `sql` too

Comment: Yes of course, I was trying with a SINGLE `INNER JOIN` and couldn't access the STAT2's description even with using an `OR` in the `ON` condition. 

The second table was the result of it.

Comment: I'm realizing that your question has [tag:abap] but you have accepted a non-ABAP answer (`SELECT t1.VBELN, ...` doesn't compile in pure ABAP). Either your question was not precise enough (missing context or wrong tag), or you accepted the wrong answer. The other one (`SELECT ... FIELDS status~vbeln, ...`) is pure ABAP (version >= 7.50).

Comment: Yes, seems like I have ticked the answer purely based on the concept and not by syntax. I have corrected it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second table has to be JOINed twice using different aliases. You did not provide the names of the tables, so I will just call the first table STATUS (vbeln, stat1, stat2), the second one TEXT (status, desc):

```
SELECT FROM status
       INNER JOIN text AS text_1
             ON status~stat1 = text_1~stats
       INNER JOIN text AS text_2
             ON status~stat2 = text_2~stats
       FIELDS status~vbeln, status~stat1, text_1~desc, status~stat2, text_2~desc
       WHERE  ...
       INTO TABLE @DATA(result).
```

Comment: For information, the syntax of ABAP code is valid only from version 7.50 (due to `FIELDS`), there is some equivalent ABAP code in older versions.